# UVM-RAL logging into file after DUT initializaton

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I want log all the UVM RAL register's along with their fields into separate file. for quick debugging. Do RAL supports any easiest way of doing it.

Thanks
Saravanan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to to that is by using the uvm built-in `sprint()` and directing all of its output to a file.

Below is an example on how to do that, assuming your register is implemented in test level:

```
class my_test extends uvm_test;
  my_reg_block my_rm;
  UVM_FILE my_file;
  //...
  function new(string name="", uvm_component parent=null);
    my_file = $fopen("register_initial.txt", "w");
    set_report_id_file("MY_REG", my_file);
    set_report_id_action("MY_REG", UVM_LOW | UVM_DISPLAY);
  endfunction
  // create your register
  function void print_register();
    `uvm_info("MY_REG", $sformatf("%s", my_rm.sprint()), UVM_LOW)
  endfunction
endclass
```

The above `print_register()` function will write the output of `my_rm.sprint()` to file "register_initial.txt".